# printing pointer address using printf in 64 bit machine

Tags: c, assembly

I have written my own code for printf. **I am using a 64 bit machine**. I am trying to print pointer address. For some reason I am getting only the lower 32 bits address. Can you help me why I am not getting the full address? My findings so far.

```
Breakpoint 1, kprintf (fmt=0xffffffff00201687 "%p") at sys/main.c:249
249                                      write_string(0x1F,"0x");
(gdb) p /x addr
$1 = 0xffffffff002050f4
```

This is my corresponding code.

```
247                       case 'p':  addr = va_arg(arg_p, uint64_t); // Print Address     of the pointer
248                                  //addr = (uint64_t) v;
249                                  write_string(0x1F,"0x");
250                                  write_string(0x1F,convert(addr,16));
251                                  break;
```

Strangely I found that the argument to convert function is **actually passed through %edi** register which is why I am getting a 32 bit value. But I am wondering why is not getting passed in %rdi register. This is my objdump / disassembly

```
 658 ffffffff00200a34:       48 89 44 24 08          mov    %rax,0x8(%rsp)
 659 ffffffff00200a39:       be 0a 00 00 00          mov    $0xa,%esi
 660 ffffffff00200a3e:       8b 39                   mov    (%rcx),%edi
 661 ffffffff00200a40:       e8 c3 01 00 00          callq  ffffffff00200c08 <convert>
```

This is how I receive arguments in convert function.

```
 13 char *convert(uint64_t num, int base)
 14 {
```

Can someone please tell me the problem here?

Edit: Adding more code

```
int kprintf(char *fmt,...){
   char *p;
   uint64_t addr;
   int i; // integer argument
   char *s; // string argument
   va_list arg_p; // pointer to the variable argument list
   va_start(arg_p, fmt); 
   for(p=fmt; *p ; p++){
           if(*p != '%'){
                   write_char(0x1F,*p);
                   continue;
           }
           switch(*++p){
                  case 'p':  addr = va_arg(arg_p, uint64_t); // Print Address of the pointer
                             //addr = (uint64_t) v;
                             write_string(0x1F,"0x");
                             write_string(0x1F,convert(addr,16));
                             break;

           }
```

My va_list

```
1 #define va_start(v,l) __builtin_va_start(v,l)
2 #define va_arg(v,l)   __builtin_va_arg(v,l)
3 #define va_end(v)     __builtin_va_end(v)
4 #define va_copy(d,s)  __builtin_va_copy(d,s)
5 typedef __builtin_va_list va_list;
```

I am calling my krpintf as follows

```
kprintf("%p",(uint64_t)&i);
```

Finally, my convert function is

```
 13 char *convert(uint64_t num, int base)
 14 {
 15 static char buf[65];
 16 char *ptr;
 17
 18 ptr=&buf[sizeof(buf)-1];
 19 *ptr='\0';
 20 do
 21 {
 22 *--ptr="0123456789abcdef"[num%base];
 23 num/=base;
 24 }while(num!=0);
 25 return(ptr);
 26 }
```

Comment: The code you posted is not at all clear, at least not to me.  You also don't say what compiler you're using, what hardware, etc.  You need to flesh out the question a wee bit more.

Comment: I have edited. Please let me know if I should explain more about my problem

Comment: How is the local variable `addr` declared?  Are you compiling with warnings turned up to a high level (`e.g. `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`)?

Comment: Local variable addr is defined as uint64_t which is inturn defined as unsigned long ( which is 8 bytes in my machine ). My compiler flags are `-Wall -Werror -nostdinc -Iinclude`

Comment: Show more code.  What is `arg_p`?  Did you call `va_start`, etc?  You're failing at the very first call to `write_string` passing only literal constants, so obviously your stack is hosed or you've got wrong calling conventions or something.

Comment: @CareyGregory I have posted my full code

Comment: `You're failing at the very first call to write_string passing only literal constants, so obviously your stack is hosed` I cant understand this. Can you please explain me. @CareyGregory

Comment: Actually, @CareyGregory. Once I removed that call it started working. But I dont understand why that should cause a 64 bit argument to be passed as 32 bit argument. I am receiving in my function as "const char *" only. Still its not good?

Comment: Did you already step through the "convert()" function? By the way: I would not use a "static buf" to be thread-safe when extending the program. I would also not use the "base" argument and allow only 16 as base so I could work with AND and SHIFT instead of DIVISION and MODULO.

Comment: Your disassembly doesn't correspond to the source, it's showing a `convert` call that takes `0x0a` (`10 dec`) as argument.

Comment: Sorry about my old comment. I didn't look at the disassembly. Are you sure the local variable "addr" is a 64-bit variable? Maybe the compiler has problems with "va_arg" when using 64-bit arguments.

Comment: Hi @all. Thank you so much for your comments. The problem was my `write_string("0x")` call as suggested by @CareyGregory. But I still couldnt figure out what I did wrong in that. I received it as a `const char *` in write_string.

Comment: @Jester Sorry about that. I was just trying to see if the integer value was getting printed to 64 bits. It dint. The culprit was my call to write_string("0x"). Can you please explain me why is that

Comment: We would need to see the code for `write_string` to know what went wrong.

Comment: Did you prototype convert()? If the compiler hasn't seen a prototype for the function, it will assume that the arguments and return type are all int. That could explain why %edi is being used instead of %rdi.

Comment: Please show the write_string function, proper disassembly, and explain where the `write_string("0x")` call is, because the code you show only has a `write_string(0x1F,"0x");` call.